# parallelize() method in SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand the effect of giving different `numSlices` to the `parallelize()` method in `SparkContext`. Given below is the `Syntax` of the method

```
def parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)
(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]
```

I ran spark-shell in **local mode**

```
spark-shell --master local
```

My understanding is, `numSlices` decides the no of partitions of the resultant RDD(after calling `sc.parallelize()`). Consider few examples below

**Case 1**

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 1);
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:22
scala> res0.partitions.size
res2: Int = 1
```

**Case 2**

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 2);
res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:22
scala> res3.partitions.size
res4: Int = 2
```

**Case 3**

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 3);
res5: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:22
scala> res3.partitions.size
res6: Int = 2
```

**Case 4**

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 4);
res7: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:22
scala> res3.partitions.size
res8: Int = 2
```

**Question 1** : In **case 3** & **case 4**, I was expecting the partition size to be `3` & `4` respectively, but both cases have partition size of only `2`. What is the reason for this?

**Question 2** : In each case there is a number associated with `ParallelCollectionRDD[no]`. ie In Case 1 it is `ParallelCollectionRDD[0]`, In case 2 it is `ParallelCollectionRDD[1]` & so on. What exactly those numbers signify?

Comment: I would like to add that, when number of partitions is not specified, Number of Threads that you specify for Spark Master configuration plays a role when Spark decides the number of slices for you. A reference would be https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/spark-parallelize-example/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Question 1**: That's a typo on your part. You're calling `res3.partitions.size`, instead of `res5` and `res7` respectively. When I do it with the correct number, it works as expected.

**Question 2**: That's the id of the [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/api/core/spark/RDD.html) in the Spark Context, used for keeping the graph straight. See what happens when I run the same command three times:

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9,1)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9,1)
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 9,1)
res2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:22
```

There are now three different RDDs with three different ids. We can run the following to check:

```
scala> (res0.id, res1.id, res2.id)
res3: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Graves for the answer. so stupid on my part to make that typo :).

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one